# traverse an object and select only a specific field

Tags: javascript

I want to traverse my `input` object and only retain the data under the `fields` key.

```
    const input = {
      fields: {
        title: 'hello',
        footer: {
          fields: {
            title: 'foo',
            text: 'bar'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const expected = {
      title: 'hello',
      footer: {
        title: 'foo',
        text: 'bar'
      }
```

So far this is my implementation of the `clean` function

```
function clean(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      obj[key] = clean(obj[key])
    }
  })
}
```

How can I make my `clean` function mutate the input as expected ?

Comment: just `Object.assign({}, input['fields'])`

Comment: @yvoytovych not really. If you notice the expected object is missing the inner `fields` object and only has its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
const input = {
  fields: {
    title: 'hello',
    footer: {
      fields: {
        title: 'foo',
        text: 'bar'
      }
    }
  }
};

function traverse(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
  if (obj.fields) return traverse(obj.fields);
  for (var i in obj) obj[i] = traverse(obj[i]);
  return obj;
}

console.log(traverse(input));
```